# Getting a backtrace for inferior process at its exit

Tags: gdb

I have a multi-threaded C++ program running on CentOS 5 exhibiting an Exit code 6 which is undesired:

```
[Inferior 1 (process 22898) exited with code 06]
```

It should be exiting with `00`. I need to debug this issue using GDB. This program is heavily multi-threaded and I'm not sure what code is running on this particular thread.

What's the best (easiest and most effective) way to catch the exit in the inferior process and get a backtrace so I can see where the thread is exiting?

I have tried setting `set detach-on-fork off` but it just ends up hanging the program.

Comment: What is your environment? Linux, something else?

Comment: Linux, CentOS5. Added to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the best way to catch the exit in the inferior process and get a backtrace so I can see where the thread is exiting?

```
(gdb) catch syscall exit_group
```